# Proving a graph has two disjoint cycles

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

For a graph A (does not contain any loops), that has every vertice of degree 6 or more, how can we prove that there exist two cycles such that s1 and s2 have set of edges disjoint from one another?

I can explain it, but I'm not sure how to write the proof formally. I can say a cycle s1 is a path that contain no repeated edges and then we can trace s2 to have vertices more than degree 2 now, and a path exist. But I'm not sure how to formally write this as a proof

Comment: Minor nitpick; the claim is false if $A$ has no vertices, and there exist infinite counterexamples as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Find one cycle, remove it's edges, prove you can find another.

For a full proof, click the spoiler:

> *It suffices to show that a graph with minimum degree $2$ or more has a cycle.* Start at any vertex, keep moving to adjacent vertices, until you get a repeat. Then you have yourself a cycle. So if $G$ is our original graph with minimum degree at least $4$, it has a cycle $S_1$. Every vertex of the cycle has $2$ edges in the cycle. So the graph $G-E(S_1)$ has minimum degree at least $2$. Thus there is a cycle $S_2$ in $G-E(S_1)$.